# Bullets CSS Confusing

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand why the bullets won't show up on [this page](http://www.drink-driving-lawyers.com.au/html-sitemap).

Initially, I thought it was due to the configs of `.postul li` on [autoptimize_b43cc31a198c21eefa915ab1cbf9453c.css](http://www.drink-driving-lawyers.com.au/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_b43cc31a198c21eefa915ab1cbf9453c.css) and so I tried adjusting it but ended up without results.

I tried inline CSS to overwrite any command for external stylesheets but still ended up with no change at all.

Further, when I tried troubleshooting via Firebug, there's this other bullet showing up for the first paragraph that's not supposed to show up.

Really confused. Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The links you've chosen make this look you are trying to build referer links to your site.

Comment: Sorry if that's how it looked like to you. I'd be happy to receive suggestions on how better to do it. I don't see any other way without spilling out the entire URL.

Comment: Posting your actual code is a good start.

Comment: Actually I'm really confused as to which codes even matter for this issue because there seems to be so many CSS files involved. Which is why to make it clearer to the readers, I put a direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this CSS, to override `autoptimize_742035cc430d7c1bb3907e3442ef5b03.css`:

```
.postul li li {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

I don't understand why you have put the first `p` in `.postul` inside a `ul>li` in the first place.

Comment: hmmm... how did you come up with that CSS file?

Comment: I didn't *come up* with it, your website did. `autoptimize` clearly generates files on the fly. The name of the file is not important. The CSS that applies is. Have you tried applying my suggestion to your CSS? Is it working?

Comment: Yeah but when I tried troubleshooting it via Firebug, the CSS file that comes up is the one I specified. So not sure how you ended up with `autoptimize_742035cc430d7c1bb3907e3442ef5b03.css`. I believe the CSS file is important because that's where you'll have to make the adjustment, right?

Comment: Re "I don't understand why you have put the first `p` in `.postul` inside a `ul>li` in the first place." ... I'm actually not the one who created the page. I am in fact trying to understand it as well.

Comment: No. Autoptimize automatically generates new files from all your assets. There is no point in changing those files, as everytime you add something to your site a new file will be generated, with another name. You should add your CSS in your (child?) theme's `style.css`.

Comment: Thanks! I did locate `postul li` on our `style.css` file and adjusted from there. It actually worked! But as expected, the first `p` was also bulleted. I'll have to dig in further on this.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but you are missing key concepts regarding web technology. You should first disable `autoptimize`. This way you will see the actual source of CSS. If you don't want your first `li` bulleted, add this to the end of your `style.css` file: `.postul>li {list-style-type: none;}` and revert your changes to the initial declaration.

Comment: Sorry about that. My earlier comment (which I deleted now) was referring to an adjustment I made to the `autoptimize` file you referred to. Thanks for the advice re disabling autoptimize during CSS troubleshoot. Will certainly take note next time.

Comment: Super thanks! The additional code to eliminate bullet for the first `p` worked!